# Comparison between USB and Mini PCIe Interfaces

Tags: google-coral

I'm deciding between the MiniPCIe and USB accelerators for a home Linux CCTV project. The host has both USB3 and a MiniPCIe socket. The host's physical environment will range from an ambient 20C up to a potential 35C (during the summer).

I'm struggling to determine the pros and cons for each. I have gotten this far, although many are guesses:

USB:

- Supports Windows and MacOS as well as Linux
- Appears to have greater mindshare/use/community support on the Internet
- External so can be placed to optimise heat dissipation
- Heatsink
- Two manual performance modes, highest requires ambient temp of max 25C
- Can use up to 4.5W (900mA @ 5V)

Mini PCie:

- Cheaper (25%)
- Lower power consumption (1.4W for 416 fps)
- Automatic thermal throttling via driver
- Relies on host system for active cooling
- Will maintain max operation at 85C

There's probably many I've missed. In particular I can't determine if there's any limitations on throughput/capacity using USB vs PCIe. If there is no difference, then I suspect the USB form factor is the better option, if only for the mindshare, although the power usage/heat generated may be a concern.

To whittle this down to an actual question: in what cases would the Mini PCIe interace be a preferred option to the USB one?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a plug&play solution, then I definitely suggest the USB Accelerator. Overall, as long as you have the [system requirements](https://coral.ai/docs/accelerator/get-started/#requirements) then it'll always works (maybe with some modifications to the standard linux configs like adding your user to the `plugdev` group, ...). Then the software for the CCTV is all up to you :)

PCIes sometimes need extra works like adding extra kernel arguments and modules to keep the pcie modules happy. If you are looking to launch a huge product where volumes are expected, then it is worth investigating it since it's cheaper and more compact. However, the power usage is a must for consideration as the USB Accelerator could uses up to 900mA, so that could play a factor.

May I know what host are you trying to attach the accelerators to?

Comment: A normal x86 Intel pc running Debian. Is that what you meant?

Comment: It's a 3ghz i3 Haswell that will be running Debian 10. The application will be Zoneminder and the plan would be to use the accelerator to play with object detection for say 8 feeds running at around 10fps. I'm not sure what model (?) will be used, I think they suggest yolov3 but I've not looked that far yet ;)

Comment: Oh I see, well, I that case, I'm not sure, my recommendation is still with USB accelerator but it is up to you :)
FYI, we haven't supported yolov3 yet, that is because the LeakyRelu ops is not yet a supported op on the edgetpu. But some user has successfully created the model using Relu instead with ~similar results.
We do have a couple of canned ssd mobilenet for object detection, here's a quick demo: https://gist.github.com/Namburger/f7e6c18af94ef3d6a70076a130eb1f7c
(it has both options of running with/without edgetpu)

Comment: Are there any limitations if using usb Vs pcie? Maybe not enough bandwidth for example? Also what does the usb do if things get too hot? Will it throttle down or even switch off?